# Find my mac tracking

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, mac, find-my-mac

Does the "Find My Mac" app automatically notify you every time your Mac is turned on? Or do you have to physically request for it notify you on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 1):

No, Find my Mac does not send any notifications to your other devices. every time it is turned on.

You may be interested in this article: [iCloud: Locate your device](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2698?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

It tells you how to see if your Mac is online or not.